# gem install bundler not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm new to ruby and working on my first project in ruby on rails. I followed the instruction given [here](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04) to install ruby on my Ubuntu 14.04(by building from source). It worked fine on my desktop. But after installing ruby on my Laptop

I'm getting error in installing bundler through gem. Here is what I did

1. First I tried installing it by typing `gem install bundler -V`, The output was:

   `HEAD https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
   200 OK
   GET https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies?gems=bundler
   200 OK
   ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
       You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 directory.`
2. Then I tried `sudo gem install bundler -V` and the output is:

   `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
         Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)`

Here are some other details that might help:

1. OS - Ubuntu 14.04
2. I'm using internet behind an authenticated proxy.
3. Ruby version: `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-linux]`
4. Rubygems version: `2.4.6`
5. OPENSSL version by typing: `ruby -ropenssl -e 'p OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'` : `"OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014"`
6. output of the command `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect rubygems.org:https`:
   `gethostbyname failure
   connect:errno=11`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your certs.

```
$ curl http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem \
> $(ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::X509::DEFAULT_CERT_FILE')
```

Credit here: http://ga.be/blog/2013/10/02/fixing-rubygems-ssl-issues-certificate-verify-failed/

If you run into other issues building from source, you may want to try `ruby-build` which is terrific IMHO because it downloads the various dependencies easily.

Comment: I removed my ruby installation and installed it using `ruby build`. It works fine now. Thanks for the advice.